# How to detect if there is a leap second when using the tm struct?

Tags: c++, c++98

According to this `struct tm` [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/), the value `tm_sec` can be `0 - 61` and the extra range is to include leap seconds in some systems. How can I  detect if there is a leap second in a system generally and in my openSUSE 13.2 machine specifically?

Comment: Are you only interested in C++98 answers? Note that the range changes in C++11 to `0-60`

Comment: 0 - 60 gives an extra second also. Either way forgot to say that I don't have C++11 support now because it is an embedded applications compiler .

Comment: OK :D I got your point :) So what about the leap second issue ?

Comment: By detect if there is a leap second, do you mean detect if the system supports it ? If not just check for tm_sec >= 60 ? There can be double leap, thats why it is 0-61

Comment: Yes I mean supports it or not. Part of my applications uses sleep command every minute and it sleeps for the rest of the minute so I need to minimize the sleep as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leap seconds are **not** related to a particular system. It is even not directly an informatic problem but rather a physical one.

In a ideal world, where every clock would be perfectly accurate, there would be no reason for leap seconds. But in our restricted world, clocks tend to deviate.

Moving the system time, specially moving it backwards can cause bad things to happen. If a batch task stores the time of its last run to know which files has already been processed and *because of the clock moving backwards* it thinks that time is now before its last run, it will process again file which may be plain wrong.

For that reason, system developpers invented the leap seconds that allow a system to adjust its system clock (of course only slight deltas, but it is generally enough if you check you clock on a regular base) without having to move it backwards.

As noted by @Supuhstar, this is just an operating system implementation of leap seconds. But leap seconds have a true physical origin and were introduced to compensate variation between two definitions of time UTC and TAI - physically variations in earth rotation speed. I give more details on it in this other [post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31315897/3545273)

Comment: You must know that they *can* occur, but you normally cannot know when.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is just wrong... actual [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) are to account for variations in the speed of the rotation of the Earth as a result of several factors. Perhaps this concept was borrowed for computers adjusting their time to match UTC, but that was not the reason they were invented.

Comment: @Supuhstar: You are right, I'll try to fix this answer. But feel free to post yours. I you do (and ping me in a comment), I'l upvote it.